Who are these characters fighting Doctor Doom on the Secret Wars #7 (2015) cover?
The cover of Secret Wars #7 (2015) by Marvel Comics features several characters from various universes within the Marvel multiverse fighting Doctor Doom. (I see Johnny Glazed / Goose Rider in there [Earth-8311, Spider-Ham's universe].) While some are easily recognizable, others are more obscure or unique variants.

Can any fellow True Believers out there help me identify these characters or which variant they are? Starting from the top left and moving counter-clockwise (I'll be updating this post to mark those not yet identified in an answer below):

A winged figure surrounded by two Spider-Men, with a cowl resembling DC's Hawkman. I'm guessing it's a variant of the Falcon since the headgear doesn't seem to match the Earth-616 iteration.

A Spider-Man variant with a predominantly red costume, below the two Spider-Men mentioned above.

A long-haired, red/brown-haired, flying figure adorned in black and gold attire.

To the right of Cyclops, a character wearing a pearlescent costume is flying and shooting energy beams from their hands. [not yet identified]

A green-skinned alien donning Captain America's costume.

A Spider-Man variant with a mostly blue costume, featuring some red spider markings on their mask.

A blonde-haired figure with feathers atop their head.

A blue entity wearing a black cloak with a large collar.

A shirtless, Conan the Barbarian-esque character wielding a lightning bolt-like weapon.

A figure brandishing a long metal staff or rod, clad in a sleeveless costume with black and metallic silver/platinum colored parts, including a metallic silver/platinum-colored helmet with black gloves. [not yet identified]

A character in a full-body black suit, wielding a baton. I"m guessing Daredevil, though this figure lacks the signature "DD" emblem and horns.

A blue-costumed individual with a red shield and a sword.

A white-haired figure sporting a white coat, black pants, and brown boots.

A black-suited character with a silver helmet, resembling Juggernaut but lacking the traditional color scheme.

A figure to the right of Captain Marvel, with a blue upper body, white lower body, and black boots.

A green, werewolf-looking character. Might be a Hulk variant?

A robotic or metallic being with transparent skin, capable of stretching their arms like a robotic Mr. Fantastic.

The most intriguing character: a figure donning a cooking implement (a strainer?) as a helmet and wielding a frying pan or similar cooking implement, clad in a red suit with a yellow "F" emblazoned on it, and a blue cloak.

A character with a multi-colored, fully body-covering costume in blue, red, yellow, and green, shooting an energy beam from their fist.


Additionally, I noticed three Spider-Men on the cover with similar costumes (counter-clockwise from top left):

Appears to be the Earth-616 Spider-Man.

A Spider-Man variant next to Star-Lord. Their costume resembles the standard Spider-Man suit, but the lenses look slightly different, akin to goggles.

A Spider-Man variant; only their left forearm is visible, wearing a retro-futuristic-looking computer bracelet.


Any fellow True Believers out there who can shed some light on these characters' identities? Excelsior!

It would help if you numbered them on the image too

I'd second #11 as Daredevil.  The cowl over the top half of his face is pretty distinctive.  From the angle you're seeing him, the DD logo on his chest would not necessarily be visible in this side view, and the horns could disappear into the shadows given that he's using the all-black version of the suit.  My question would be - what is he standing on?  What is anyone standing on?  Sure, some of these characters can fly, but most of them can't.  They all seem to be just floating in space...

@JiminyCricket. OP is asking only about the characters that he can't identify.

Oh, yes, I see it now. @RubioRic

@DarrelHoffman It seems that they're using poor ol' Doom as a makeshift platform. Also, I'm not sure how much Daredevil and his billy clubs would help in that fight.


Psi-Hawk (New Universe, Earth-148611)



Spider-Girl (Earth-X, Earth-9997)



Helen Taylor (Earth-79715 version of Nova) (See @LogicDictates' answer)
? (Iron Man variant with green armor)
Captain America (Excalibur vol.1 #14, Earth 8910)



Spider-Man 2099



Rojhaz (Captain America Native-American variant, 1602, Earth-311) Thanks to @Arclite!



Doctor Strange (Midnightsons, 1990s)



Arkon



?
Daredevil (See @LogicDictates' answer)
Shieldsman (Galactic Avengers, Avengers Forever, Earth-9812, designed by Carlos Pacheco)



Justice (New Universe, Earth-148611)



J2 (MC2 Universe, Earth-982)



Captain Britain



Hulk 2099



Machine-Man (Earth-X, Earth-9997) - Not 100% sure



Irving Forbush



Doctor Spectrum (Squadron Supreme, Earth-712)



Spider-Man (Earth-616?)

Spider-Man from 1970s TV Series (Earth-730911)




Spider-Man (Earth-51778)



Given your description of "Captain America Native-American version", I think that #7 is Rojhaz, the version of Steve Rogers from Marvel 1602.

@Arclite: Agreed, this facepaint is what he puts on right at the end of that series.

I've updated my question to ask about the three Spider-Men on the cover who share similar costume designs. If you happen to know their respective identities, please feel free to incorporate that information into your answer.

@galacticninja I've updated my answer accordingly. :-) Not sure if 20 is Earth-616's variant and I don't know if 21 is associated with a specific earth.

Wow, New Universe characters. Been a while since I thought of any of those characters. The football players from Kickers Inc. were probably too overpowered to fight Doom.



A long-haired, flying figure adorned in black and gold attire.


That could be the Earth-79715 version of Nova, Helen Taylor. In her reality, the dying Nova Corps Centurion, Rhomann Dey, transferred his powers to her instead of Rich Ryder (who received them on Earth-616).


What If? Vol. 1 #15 (July, 1979)




A character in a full-body black suit, wielding a baton. I"m guessing Daredevil, though this figure lacks the signature "DD" emblem and horns.


That could be the Earth-400005 version of Daredevil from the The Trial of the Incredible Hulk (1989) TV-movie, a follow-up to the The Incredible Hulk TV series (1978–1982).

When Banner is held as a witness to a violent crime linked to the Kingpin, the fugitive is helped by lawyer Matt Murdock who is also the superhero, Daredevil.



As a side note, according to Wikipedia, this TV-movie featured the first ever cameo of Stan Lee in a Marvel movie or TV project, outside of narrating.

In the TV-movie The Trial of the Incredible Hulk (1989), Lee's first appearance in a Marvel movie or TV project, outside of narrating is as a jury foreman in the trial of Dr. David Banner.





The green-skinned figure in the bottom-right corner of the image in the question also resembles the live-action version of the Hulk from the same universe.

I've updated my question to ask about the three Spider-Men on the cover who share similar costume designs. If you happen to know their respective identities, please feel free to incorporate that information into your answer.

Great findings! :-)
